# showing refresh page button when there is no internet connection

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-progressbar

I have an activity that requires an internet connection, and I put a progress bar for loading pages, but when there is no internet connection from the user the progress bar is always *VISIBLE*, like the code below

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BlogModel blogModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(BlogModel.class);
        blogModel.getBlogList().observe(this,getBlog);
        blogModel.setBlog("extra_blog");


        showLoad(true);
}

private Observer<ArrayList<BlogItem>> getBlog = new Observer<ArrayList<BlogItem>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ArrayList<BlogItem> blogItems) {
        if (blogItems != null){
            adapter.setData(blogItems);
        }
        showLoad(false);
    }
};

private void showLoad(Boolean state){
    if (state){
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

and what I want is, when there is no internet connection, the progress bar has the status of *GONE* and immediately **showing the button**, and this button will function to **refresh the activity**, is there any solution related to this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to check if you are connected to the internet like this:

```
boolean connected = false;
ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED || 
        connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
    //we are connected to a network
    connected = true;
}
else
    // not connected
    connected = false;
```

Just set Progresssbar Gone when you are not connected.
You will need this permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```